# About the new Xubuntu 22.04 window system and sound server

Tags: xubuntu

I have two questions about the new **Xubuntu 22.04**.

1. Is it using **X11** or has it switched to **Wayland**?
2. Is it using **Pulseaudio** or has it switched to **Pipewire**?

I emphasize that I'm asking about **Xubuntu** specifically. Not any other flavours.

Thank you.

Comment: Pulseadio 16 and Pipewire are both mentioned in the [release notes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403758/about-the-new-xubuntu-22-04), and I doubt Xubuntu has any support for Wayland.

Comment: Please edit the title of this question to reflect the actual question. Note that questions should be focused: one specific question, one specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wayland is the default display server on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. However, you can choose to use an X11 session.Nothing is mentioned in the XFCE or Xubuntu documentation, however xfwm (the window manager for XFCE4) doesn't work on Wayland, and XFCE4 really isn't designed to work on it yet. You could probably work around that by using a different window manager and layering XFCE on top of a KDE or Gnome install (running XFCE on X-11 inside a virtual environment inside one of them) but what's the point of that?  I haven't run Wayland yet, and don't intend to, and hope XFCE never supports it.
22.04 uses Pulseaudio 16 by default. You can also remove Pulseaudio and use Alsa and maybe Jack, if you prefer, since Pulseaudio and Pipewire are useless features. If you install pipewire, be sure to install any additional libraries: bluetooth, Gstreamer, Jack.. and some programs written for Pulse won't recognise Pipe even so. So, no, Pipe is not installed.